# Super-strong genetically modified super-soldier?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, super-powers

My question is: What needs to be changed or improved in the structure of human muscle fibers so that my genetically modified person can lift several tons ( from 700 to 3200 kilograms), taking into account the fact that this person weighs no more than 110-140 kilograms.
That is, I need this Superman to have a huge, compared to ordinary people, physical strength.

To understand the limits of human physical capabilities, here are the best physical data of world athletes.

The record in the bench press in the bezekipirovachny division, today belongs to Kirill Sarych and is 335 kilograms (at a time).

The record in equipment belongs to Ryan Camely and is 486 kilograms.

The record of lifting the bar up over the head, with a push, belongs to Leonid Taranenko and is 267 kilograms.

In deadlift (lift above the ground), the record is about 500 kilograms.

Supplement: I need solutions related to biology. So no magic, Cybernetics, or exoskeletons. I ask about changes in the structure of the human body. In other words, what needs to be changed in the structure of the human body so that it has great physical strength, but at the same time looks like an ordinary person.

Comment: While you research the genetics, the russians use pencils to write in 0g and the P-5000 heavy loader as a powered exoskeleton when needed. Because why would they want to feed a giant all the time when such traits are rarely needed?

Comment: Also, one problem with super-human strength which is often conveniently ignored is inertia and mass. You could lift it, sure, but not much else - you would be flung around by the weight. Add in bone structure and nutritional problems @Adrian mentioned. No meals outside the meal plan.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi AFAIK the main problem with powered exoskeletons is the lack of agility. So in combat, for elite operators, it's a no go.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi why? As a group of elite operators specialized in spaceship boarding action in a scifi setting where every ship uses gravitation-manipulating deck plating. Which can be overridden upwards of 2g.

Comment: The first thought that comes to mind is that they need access to magic. What are the limits for your setting-- is that a suitable answer?

Comment: @JanDorniak Space operations, right? With gravity plates. So you have a level of manipulating energies in excess of what the Earth technology is able to produce nowadays, but you still want to use muscle power. To my mind [sounds like bringing a knife to a gun fight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YyBtMxZgQs), but again... it's not my space-opera setup, who am I to judge?

Comment: Actually, the author makes it sound reasonable. Sometimes you just have to do boarding action. With no wireless connection hack/jam proof and the lack of agility of powered exoskeletons what are you going to use? Though I have to add it's a HFY story so humans are powerful in that universe by design.

Comment: For amusement, if I were to use grav-plates, as a counter-measure to an attack inside, I'd put one row of those in the ceiling too. Then I'd start playing a sorta non lethal ball game with the boarders, by oscillating those grav fields, bouncing them between the floor and the ceiling. Should make for some good fun scenes.

Comment: @JanDorniak "what are you going to use?" Heaps of very agile monkeys to overload you ability to focus your defense or a source of power those grav plates can't withstand.

Comment: I need my genetically modified person (genetic engineering ) to look more or less like a person, but at the same time can raise a few tone . What needs to be changed in the structure of the muscles and skeleton to do this?

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question. You dont care about genetic modification but about custom-build biological systems that can grow, regenerate and sustain itself. So this question should be as follows: "what kind of system could be considered biological and grant the most strength to a humanoid creature". You can add some constraints such as how long they should maintain this strength or how fast they need to be able to contract. Also perhaps you should check out some of my previous questions:

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/115986/creating-a-scientifically-semi-valid-super-soldier-part-8-communication?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1):

7000 kg is *a lot*. There's no easy trick that will suddenly enable your superhero to become this super human without resorting to either hand waving or things you've prohibited (cybernetics/robotics mostly). As for the answer to your question, what needs to be changed? Almost everything about the human body, if it's even possible at all.

For starters, there are a couple "biological" handwave-y things you can do:

- Grow bones out of graphene or carbon nanotube composites. This gives the person a black skeleton which is extremely tough and capable of withstanding massive forces
- Make ligaments, tendons, and other structural components out of the body out of supermaterials too, anything from graphene-handwave to "spider silk" ligaments
- Rework muscles so that they are much stronger and more compact. Maybe you can throw some supermaterial buzzwords in here to or some generalization of "radical bio engineering"

In summary, without resorting to "magic", I don't think it's possible to make a human that can safely lug around 7000 kg while staying under 140 kg. Fleshy building materials like bones, ligaments, and muscles simply don't have the material properties to do this. Even if you scavenged the bones from the strongest-boned animal and the muscles from the animal with the most dense muscles, it still wouldn't work. For example, an adult silverback gorilla is estimated to be able to lift 815 kg dead. Even if that's inaccurate, that's still nowhere near your requirements (close to an order of magnitude off). The same silverback masses in at about 160 kg and silverbacks are generally at the top when you consider animal individual muscle strength densities.

Comment: I need to create a biologically and scientifically realistic super Soldier, how can you create carbon nanotubes and other types of nanotechnology in your body (naturally)?!
This is unreal!

Comment: @FrenchThompson Human bodies are extremely information dense. With current manufacturing technology we can't make a human brain because the neural density is simply too high--everything is too detailed. However, biological cells are used to building large structures from the 'nanoscale' up. Bones, tissue, and brains are all examples of this, and comparatively, the crystalline structures of materials such as graphene or carbon nanotubes are simple enough that they could conceivably be assembled by biological cells.

Comment: Can you describe the process of creating these super strong bones and tendons in your answer ( please provide the calculations )?

Comment: I have rewritten my question a bit, I advise you to look at it.