# Superhuman strength?

Tags: science-based, creature-design

According to my story, after the extinction of mankind several centuries in the future, a new improved species was created using genetic engineering.  people superior to us in everything: in intelligence, strength, ability to survive in extremely unpleasant conditions for us and life expectancy.
It just so happened that these creatures did not differ too much outwardly from the representatives of homo sapiens, except perhaps for the huge head of Graham, created by the Australian sculptor Patricia Paccini, and rather impressive height and body weight: 350 centimeters and approximately 450-600 kilograms.

And here we come to the essence of my question, as already mentioned above, this new type of superhuman, as well as in terms of intelligence, should surpass us in physical strength, however, given how much it weighs, it would be an imaginary superiority, because just getting on his feet he is already  will lift quite a decent weight of his body, but I need him to be able to lift proportionally more than his body weight, for example, I will give the best physical data of world athletes:

The record in the bench press in the unskilled division, today belongs to Kirill Sarych and is 335 kilograms (at a time).

The record in equipment belongs to Ryan Cameli and is 486 kilograms.

The record for lifting the bar up overhead, with a push, belongs to Leonid Taranenko and is 267 kilograms.

In herd traction (lift above the ground), the record is about 500 kilograms.

As you can see, relatively ordinary people who have undergone physical training can lift huge weights over themselves, in some cases even exceeding their body weight.
And here comes my question: how much weight can my supermen lift?

Comment: Part of the question is verbatim copied from https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/169950/30492

Comment: It's not true, there the weight of a genetically modified person did not exceed 150 kilograms, while my set bar is 450 kg, they also ask about the possibility (and ways to do it) to lift more than 3000 kilograms.
These are different questions.

Comment: This was an old question of mine and since then the idea for which it was created has changed a bit.

Comment: I am not saying it's a duplicate question. I am just saying that part of the text is exactly the same.

Comment: I think the proper thing to do is to give credit to the question with copied text (it would probably be less of a big deal if it were associated with your current account)

Comment: This falls into a category of questions I define as follows: How much wood can a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood? He would chuck all the wood that a woodchuck would chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood. It's your story, so you can have them lift as much as you want. If you want specifics, you need to provide specific information about the nature and biology of muscles, tendons, bones, cartilage, etc. There's far, far too much information missing to actually answer your question with anything other than speculation and assumption.

Answer (score 2):

With their bodies at "350 centimeters and approximately 450-600 kilograms.", and using the same layout as humans?

Your supermen will not be able to run. Possibly not to walk even.

Bipedal stance, and that sort of mass, really do not go well with the sort of bones humans are made of in a human-like configuration.

You would need leg bones (and attendant musculature) to be much,much thicker. Very much more so than the x2 scaling you use on body length.

The body proportion would be squat and wide. This in turn would mean that by the time you get to 350cm height, the mass would be *way* over 450-600 kg. Think more in the 1.5 tonne range. Your superman will resemble half an elephant, instead of appearing human.

Answer (score 1):

It’s simple: Increase muscle and bone density so that the weight can be supported more. As they’re approximately twice as tall, they’d have approximately 8 times the mass, and 4 times the area, due to the square-cube law. So, they’d need to be twice as strong per mass, so their relative strength is the same as humans. And their absolute strength would be 8 times human levels, instead of just 4 times.

Comment: If you have 8 times the volume AND you have increased the bone and muscle density to compensate strength, you have more than 8 times the mass.

Comment: Could you describe how much they can lift?

Comment: French Thompson, if we have an average human who can lift 40 kg, and we’re dealing with a being that’s eight times as massive, and has the same proportional strength, then they can lift 320 kg.