Enhanced human capable of killing any predator on land with bare hands
Basically, a genetically engineered humanoid that maxes out on all stats. Engineered to,

Have a larger density of skeletal muscles.
Have a high bone density
Highly enhanced senses and reaction times (like that of a cat).
Brain developed to increase combat capability.
Body structure changed to be better at fighting.
Regenerative capabilities and biological immortality.

So my questions are,
a) Is this achievable according to science?
b) What are the limits?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'd think of this person like a tank: they're not outright immune to anything, but resistant to certain things — some to a great degree, some to a lesser one. For instance, to a main battle tank, 12.7mm machine gun fire is no threat, 30mm autocannon fire is more, a full-on tank shell even to the frontal armor array has a decent chance of destroying it. A stoat will be zero threat to this human. A wolf, more. A bear has that decent chance. These things you ask for may or may not be possible but I'd encourage changing the way you think about it.

@byebye 1. and 2. are definitely possible 3. and 4. might be difficult to engineer because the brain is very complex. Though with a little hand waiving or advanced technology this is still possible. I don't really know what you mean with 5. though. 6. Is difficult but hey not impossible there are enough technical immortal species out there.

Before we vote to close your question (a) We've had all of these attributes addressed in other questions on this stack, making this question a duplicate of many others. (b) Asking more than one question (you are... you're asking 12 questions...) is literally a reason to vote to close a question. (c) Even if it weren't, this question violates the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule (it's way too broad). (d) We're willing to help you create the denizens of your imaginary world. We're not willing to create them for you. (e) Finally, you're going to be disappointed by the answers... (*Continued*)

... while we can use science as a reference to rationalize attributes like these (see all those other questions I mentioned), science can't actually achieve much of any of these things. (It's a lot more fun to build imaginary worlds where science guides us into imaginative solutions rather than using it to restrictively bind us.) Long story short... (f) Please [edit] the post to address one specific problem that's unique and not previously addressed in another question. Thanks.

We probably could do 90% of this if we really wanted to for some reason as I noted in my answer. It would mostly be pointless, because guns can easily kill enhanced humans and enhanced humans would be expensive to build, but we could do most of it. The only impossible thing is biological immortality, and why do you even need that for a shock trooper? If they die just make more.

Although I understand many people want 'superhumans' in their stories, I never understand why they need to be this overdone. The whole reason for military technology is to make it trivial to kill for as many people as possible. With training and adequate weapons, you can have an 8yo face a bear, tiger or elephant. In our day and age we can have a soldier that never would've passed any test for WWII sit behind a computer and wreak absolute mayhem with a drone, killing thousands of physically better soldiers. Supersoldiers have more and more a limited use.

As @JBH says many of these are already individually answered. You can check out the 'supersoldier' series of Demigan for example. A collection can be found here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/143003/creating-a-scientifically-semi-valid-super-soldier-addendum-metabolism

Note that "maxes out on all stats" is inherently impossible - the fastest person/vehicle/animal will never be the strongest because of opposing requirements and so on.  Which is why sprinters, martial artists and weight lifters do not compete against each other - there are trade offs in being good at one thing that reduce ability in other fields.  As mentioned by others, humans excel in using tools (and teamwork) to achieve feats that no other animal can.

Addressing the question title; anything that can kill a hippopotamus with its bare hands isn't going to look "human" anymore.

Chimpanzees can do most of this.
Chimpanzees are twice as strong as humans, have denser bones, have better senses of smell, have natural instincts to fight harder, have long limbs which are great at ripping off enemy limbs, and can use crushed insects to help heal wounds faster.
Biological immortality is a much harder question, but you could certainly make some sort of human chimpanzee or gorilla hybrid that could be pretty brutal in urban combat. Give it some tweaks to make it peak performance  e.g. faster muscle and bone growth and you'd have a pretty dangerous soldier.
For immortality, you might want to make some sort of hibernation/cold blood mode. It would take some impressive engineering but you could probably make them have a cold blooded mode so they could rest for long periods between missions and live longer.

Chimpanzees are NOT 2x as strong as humans. There muscles are at MOST 1.5x stronger than human muscles of the same size and many (if not most) adult men have more “strength” than a chimpanzee. They are only stronger pound for pound.

Partial answer, since the is it possible part is already addressed

What are the limits?

The limits are that some species, someday will develop the ability to use tools that render an ability to kill something with your bare hands obsolete.
Earth has many apex and otherwise highly effective predators, for example, grizzly bears, alligators and crocodiles, Great White sharks, Orcas, pythons, king cobras, Komodo dragons, honey badgers, lions, tigers, and great apes.
None of them are much of a threat to modern humans, most are going extinct, and a super-humanoid who could kill anything with its bare hands would be threatened rather than being a threat too.
The ability to use tools, like ranged weapons, fast moving vehicles, and traps, is a superpower that can defeat any bare handed opponent.
The other limit on any apex predator is that there are enough prey species to support it. If it is too effective and kills everything in one go, wasting food, it will starve in the next season. Overkill probably happened with humans historically and is a risk faced by any apex predator.

Most of them is chimpanzee feature, as the other answer already says.
What is not:
Huge IQ: it is not known, if more or a better developed brain actually results more intelligence. The elephants or the dolphins have a larger brain as we have, yet would it be hard to say that they are smarter (although they are among the smartest of the animals).
Regeneration, immortality: Probably achievable, but not with the science of the today. Note that immortal lifeforms or lifeforms which can regenerate lost limbs, there are all very simple.
Beside that, our body is formed in large part by external forces and not only by DNA.
Very likely, while it would be possible (if it could grow once, it can again), the result would probably not look like your first arm (leg). Also immortality would more likely result a "human" more similar to a cancerous tumor on the long-term.
